# Exported Excel from HTML table not opening in google sheets

Tags: javascript, html, excel, google-sheets

I had written `javascript` function to convert HTML table to Excel (done) but when I try to open my exported excel in google sheets it give me response something like this

[image: exported excel in google sheets]

what changes I need to make in my `prototype JS function` to resolve this issue

```
  handleexportExcel :function(){
    var self = this;
    $(".monthly-payments-report-details #paymentExcelReport").unbind('click');
    $(".monthly-payments-report-details #paymentExcelReport").click(function(e){
      var payment_report_table_html = "<table border='2px'>";
      var monthly_payment_report_table = document.getElementById('monthlyPaymentReportTable');
      for(index = 0 ; index < monthly_payment_report_table.rows.length-1 ; index++)
      {
        payment_report_table_html += monthly_payment_report_table.rows[index].innerHTML+"</tr>";
      }
      payment_report_table_html += "</table>";
      var anchor_html_excel = document.createElement('a');
      anchor_html_excel.href = 'data:application/vnd.ms-excel' + ', ' + encodeURIComponent(payment_report_table_html);
      anchor_html_excel.download = 'Payment Report_' + self.start_date + '_' + self.end_date + '.xls';
      anchor_html_excel.click();
    })
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Google Sheets is showing you exactly what you exported.

Just because Excel decides to show an HTML table as a worksheet, doesn't mean the GS developers are obliged to include that functionality.

If you want to export an actual Excel file then use a different method in your js.

Comment: Thankx for your suggestion. Please can you share which method definition will solve my issue

Comment: You will need to use an approach which will output a "real" Excel file, but requests to recommend tools/libraries are off-topic on SO (and I have no experience with doing this). Something like https://github.com/SheetJS/js-xlsx might work for you.